# Text left, figure WITH CAPTION right

Tags: floats, captions

I try to get the text at the left side of the document and the figure on 
the right side of the document. Unfortunately, there are still some issues:
In the first example, the lettering differs (font, gaps, type) from the lettering of the main text.
In the second example, no caption appears.
I could not find any solution so far and would be really grateful about any help from you!

1) Example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   sfsdaa
   sdfsfasfs
   10L-bach of water that flows through the device, it dispenses a dose of 3 mL of NaOCl solution into a mixing chamber. The chlorinated water is then flushed by an automatic siphon into a storage reservoir and dispensed via a tap \citep{Amin2016}.
Difficulties experienced with the application of this device
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
     \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Zimba.PNG}
      \caption{Bild rechts}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

2) Example

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
     \noindent {\textbf{Zimba}}\\
    The Zimba device is connected to handpumps. For every 10L-bach of water that flows through the device, it dispenses a dose of 3 mL of NaOCl solution into a mixing chamber. The chlorinated water is then flushed by an automatic siphon into a storage reservoir and dispensed via a tap \citep{Amin2016}.
    Difficulties experienced with the application of this device
    are the variations in dosing due to clogging of the regulator \citep{Pickering2015}. Moreover, the Zimba dispenser uses a non-standard low concentration NaOCl solution (0.4\%), which requires dilution before filling.
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Zimba.PNG}
       %\rule{0.9\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
       \caption{Zimba \citep{Amin2016}}
       \label{fig:Zimba}
    \end{minipage}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/sidecap/sidecap.pdf

Comment: Without the figure, use \captionof{figure} from the caption or capt-of packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! I could solve the problem with \captionof{figure}[Dosage float]{Dosage float}.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit like you are trying to do something that is implemented by the `wrapfig` package. Here is an easy example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Bild rechts}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

With the output being:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \begin{document} 
\begin{tabular} {p{6cm} p{5cm}}
    {\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   sfsdaa
   sdfsfasfs
   10L-bach of water that flows through the device, it dispenses a dose of 3 mL of NaOCl solution into a mixing chamber. The chlorinated water is then flushed by an automatic siphon into a storage reservoir and dispensed via a tap .
Difficulties experienced with the application of this device
    \end{minipage}\hfill} &
    {\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
     \centering
    I would like to say that I do not have any pictures, text or table. % \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]
%      \caption{Bild rechts}
    \end{minipage}}
  \end{tabular}\\
  \vspace{1cm}

 \begin{tabular} {p{6cm} p{5cm}}
    {\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
     \noindent {\textbf{Zimba}}\\
    The Zimba device is connected to handpumps. For every 10L-bach of water that flows through the device, it dispenses a dose of 3 mL of NaOCl solution into a mixing chamber. The chlorinated water is then flushed by an automatic siphon into a storage reservoir and dispensed via a tap.
    Difficulties experienced with the application of this device
    are the variations in dosing due to clogging of the regulator . Moreover, the Zimba dispenser uses a non-standard low concentration NaOCl solution (0.4\%), which requires dilution before filling.
    \end{minipage}} & 

    {\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
       \centering

       Some thing is missing here
       %\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Zimba.PNG}
       %\rule{0.9\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
       %\caption{Zimba \citep{Amin2016}}
       \label{fig:Zimba}
    \end{minipage}}

    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

% please compile with full tex. I hope this is useful to you. I compiled it and saw that it works.

Comment: Please add a coment on how this solves the question. Ther is no caption in your cdoe, while the OP explicitly requested a figure with a caption.